# Why does `Trace.Writeline()` lack the `WriteLine(string format, params Object[] args)` overload?

Tags: c#, .net

[Debug.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc190153.aspx) has an overload with the following signature:

`public static void WriteLine(string format, params Object[] args)`

[Trace.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not have that overload (although it has all the others that `Debug.WriteLine()` has).

Does anyone know the reason for this omission?

There's no reason for me to avoid it myself, I assume? (I only ask because I'm implementing a logging interface, and the default implementation will just use `Debug.WriteLine()` and `Trace.WriteLine()` and I want to be aware of any weird ramifications. I can't imagine any though.)

Comment: I have this vision of a BCL designer/developer who worked on this 10 years ago reading this question and laughing. Laughing maniacally.

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't surprise me. :)

Comment: Either they never thought to add it or couldn't be bothered to take the time.  Either call `string.Format` and pass the results in, or write your own method with the desired signature that passes the formatted results to Trace.  We're very unlikely to ever know the specific reason some other person choose, and we're certainly not the ones in a position to have the BCL changed.

Comment: @Servy: That's effectively what I've done. I'm just writing a logging wrapper (in this case, for NLog) but the default implementation just writes to Debug.WriteLine() and Trace.WriteLine() - which is why I came across the issue. I don't expect there to be any real reason, but I was asking just in case.

Comment: Actually, the `Debug.WriteLine(string, object[])` overload was only added in 4.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline%28v=vs.100%29.aspx So maybe a BCL developer from only 3 years ago. :(

Comment: Now that's interesting. I hadn't noticed that. I guess there's no real reason that I need to worry about though.

Comment: You should not edit an answer to your question into the question.  If you have found a solution to your own problem then post an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well*, I not sure what I say but I take a chance.

When I decompiled these methods, they both use the same `TraceInternal.WriteLine(string)` method.

When I decompile `Debug.WriteLine Method (String, Object[])`;

```
public static void WriteLine(string format, params object[] args)
{
   TraceInternal.WriteLine(string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args));
}
```

When I decompile `Trace.WriteLine(string)`;

```
public static void WriteLine(string message)
{
   TraceInternal.WriteLine(message);
}
```

As you can see, only difference is, the first one using `string.format()` method. Looks like it is no big deal to me..

But *why of the omission*? I have no idea. As ken2k [*mentioned*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501897/why-does-trace-writeline-lack-the-writelinestring-format-params-object#comment21949412_15502160), I believe this can be answered totaly by base class library developers only..

Comment: While this is true, the question was more about the *why* of the omission IMO. That being said, I guess only the BCL developers can answer that anyway...

Comment: @ken2k You are totally right. I have no idea the _omission_ part.

Comment: Yes, to be honest I could have phrased the question better. I was concerned about why they omitted it, and was there a reason I should also omit it. It turns out that there is a reason not to provide that particular method signature (IMO) - see my edited question.

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered a reason why I shouldn't add such an interface in my own code: Because it's misleading.

At first glance, I thought that

`Debug.WriteLine("Value = {0}", "Test");`

would print:

`Value = Test`

But in fact it prints:

`Test: Value = {0}`

The reason this is so misleading is because there are so many similar methods which do formatting like that, such as `string.Format()`, `Console.WriteLine()` and so on.

So really, such a misleading function should be avoided, IMHO.

This doesn't really answer my original question directly - but it explains why the method was not originally in .Net. It does not explain why they added it in a later version. I am now of the opinion that they should not have.

(I've now circumvented the problem in my code by copying what NLog does - I require the class name to be passed (via a factory method) to the constructor of my logging class, so that the class name is never passed to any of the message formatters.)